# Directory with date in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batchfile but I'm stuck at the part where my directory with today's date has to come. At this moment I get:

C:\Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow

but I want to get:

C:\Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow\dateoftoday

The date of today should be in YYYY-MM-DD.

Beneath is a piece of code that I have and it would be very helpful if someone could adapt this cause I am without a clue at the moment.

```
 @echo on

set LogFilePath=C:\ProgramData\Proficy\Logs
set OutputFilePath=C:\Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow
set X=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x

set DATE.YEAR=%X:~0,4%
set DATE.MONTH=%X:~4,2%
set DATE.DAY=%X:~6,2%
set mydate=%DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%

mkdir "%OutputFilePath%"
cd /d %LogFilePath%

xcopy /s /f /y "%LogFilePath%\ProficyClient.log" "%OutputFilePath%\%mydate%\*"
xcopy /s /f /y "%LogFilePath%\SOAServer.log" "%OutputFilePath%\%mydate%\*"
```

Comment: What does not work as you expect? The code should work fine (although it can be done easier). You want to copy two dedicated `.log` files, right? so why do you state `xcopy`'s `/S` option?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for concerning the mydate environment variable?

```
set mydate=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%
```

I would probably add your `set OutputFilePath` after the mydate stuff and just make the OutputFilePath be the whole thing.

```
set OutputFilePath=C:\Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow\%mydate%
```

Lastly, instead of xcopy I would recommend robocopy. The syntax is a little unusual, but it's much more resilient and has other options that make it more suitable to run inside a batch file.

Comment: Now i use the code suggested by you, but I now get: 

C:\Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow\-4\-01

So almost there but not quite yet! Do you see where the problem is, cause I have never written a batchfile before.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code that got me the wanted batchfile with the wanted directory!

```
@echo on

set LogFilePath=C:\ProgramData\Proficy\Logs
set X=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x

set DATE.YEAR=%X:~0,4%
set DATE.MONTH=%X:~4,2%
set DATE.DAY=%X:~6,2%
set mydate=%DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%

set OutputFilePath=C:\Dimensys Preventive Maintenance\07 LogFiles\Workflow\%mydate%

mkdir "%OutputFilePath%"
cd /d %LogFilePath%

robocopy /s /f /y "%LogFilePath%\ProficyClient.log" "%OutputFilePath%\%mydate%\*"
robocopy /s /f /y "%LogFilePath%\SOAServer.log" "%OutputFilePath%\%mydate%\*"
```

Thanks @theglossy1, you pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: Good choice using `wmic` to mitigate regional differences in date formatting. This will work everywhere. Using `set "mydate=%X:~0,4%-%X:~4,2%-%X:~6,2%"` would obviate the need for several variables.

Comment: I cannot believe that this does what you want, because you are appending the date directory twice...